# Create safe deep property accessor from Lambda with Expressions

Tags: c#, expression-trees

My goal is to use Lambdas to create a property binding object that can do a safe retrieval of a deep property value. By safe, it returns the default value of the property type if one of previous properties is null rather than throwing a null reference exception.

The method signature:

```
public static Func<TO, TP> BuildSafeAccessor<TO, TP>(this Expression<Func<TO, TP>> propertyExpression) where TO: class
{
}
```

*Edit: Clarify my question

So if I call:

```
var safeAccessor = BuildSafeAccessor<Person>(p => p.Address.Zip);
```

When safeAccessor is called, it's logic would be the following:

```
if (p.Address == null)
    return default(TP);
return p.Address.Zip;
```

Comment: Can you be explicit: what is the *question* here?

Comment: I would like to know how to construct the Expression that will compile into a safe accessor. The body of my BuildSafeAccessor method.

Comment: I keep coming across issues in how the Expressions are built, particularly Expression.Condition(test, ifTrue, ifFalse) where I need the ifFalse expression fully created already. May have something that works in a bit.

Comment: I have and all I've found is building an Expression with a string for a deep property. Nothing that will not throw a null reference exception. If you know differently, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation here is that you don't need “the ifFalse expression fully created already”, you can build it recursively.

The code could look like this:

```
public static Func<TO, TP> BuildSafeAccessor<TO, TP>(Expression<Func<TO, TP>> propertyExpression)
{
    var properties = GetProperties(propertyExpression.Body);
    var parameter = propertyExpression.Parameters.Single();
    var nullExpression = Expression.Constant(default(TP), typeof(TP));

    var lambdaBody = BuildSafeAccessorExpression(parameter, properties, nullExpression);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TO, TP>>(lambdaBody, parameter);

    return lambda.Compile();
}

private static Expression BuildSafeAccessorExpression(Expression init, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties, Expression nullExpression)
{
    if (!properties.Any())
        return init;

    var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(init, properties.First());
    var nextStep = BuildSafeAccessorExpression(propertyAccess, properties.Skip(1), nullExpression);

    return Expression.Condition(
        Expression.ReferenceEqual(init, Expression.Constant(null)), nullExpression, nextStep);
}

private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Expression expression)
{
    var results = new List<PropertyInfo>();

    while (expression is MemberExpression)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
        results.Add((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member);
        expression = memberExpression.Expression;
    }

    if (!(expression is ParameterExpression))
        throw new ArgumentException();

    results.Reverse();

    return results;
}
```

(Note that this code uses LINQ inefficiently, to make it more readable.)

If you run it on the lambda `a => a.B.C.D`, it will create an expression (showing the result of `ToString()` on it):

```
a => IIF((a == null), null, IIF((a.B == null), null, IIF((a.B.C == null), null, a.B.C.D)))
```

Notice that this accesses `a.B` up to three times. If that property is slow or has side effects, that could be a problem. If this is a problem to you, I think you would need to use `Block`s with local variables.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I knew recursion had to come into play, it was just escaping my grasp!